# Is there a way to manually clear ram in python 3.7?

Tags: python, ram

I am trying to make a program that removes the background in a video so that only the foreground is shown. It works for short videos, but on longer ones it slows down exponentially and begins using more and more memory so that the program crashes.

I have tried deleting the variables used in for loops as shown in the code below.

```
def video_generator(name_of_video, video, cap, number_of_frames):
    check, frame = cap.read()
    A = np.array([])
    a = np.array([])

    if cap.isOpened():
        width = int(cap.get(3))
        height = int(cap.get(4))

    dims = (height, width)

    while cap.isOpened():
        check, frame = cap.read()

        if check:
            gray = cv2.cvtColor(frame, cv2.COLOR_BGR2GRAY).flatten()
            A = np.append(A, gray)
            a = np.append(a, 'row')
            image = cv2.cvtColor(frame, cv2.COLOR_BGR2GRAY) 
        else:
            break   

    B = np.resize(A, (number_of_frames, width * height))

    U, S, V = decomposition.randomized_svd(B, 2)
    background = U @ np.diag(S) @ V

    foreground = ([])

    def generate_frames(B, background):
        for i in range(number_of_frames):
            foreground = np.reshape(B[i] - background[i], dims)
            frame = plt.imshow(foreground, cmap = 'gray')
            plt.savefig('D:/Python_Programs/BR_SVD/Frames/' + name_of_video + '/file_' + str(i + x * number_of_frames).zfill(2) + '.png')   

            del frame
            del foreground
            gc.collect()

    generate_frames(B, background)  

if number_of_frames_initial <= 200:
    cap = cv2.VideoCapture(video)
    video_generator(name_of_video, video_initial, cap_initial, number_of_frames_initial)

else:
    number_of_videos = int(number_of_frames_initial/200 + 1)
    time_of_videos = duration/number_of_videos

    for x in range (number_of_videos):

        subprocess.call ([
            'ffmpeg', '-i', video_initial, '-ss', str(time_of_videos * x), '-t', str(time_of_videos), 'D:/Python_Programs/BR_SVD/Temp_Videos/video_%02d.mp4' % x])

        video = 'D:/Python_Programs/BR_SVD/Temp_Videos/video_%02d.mp4' % x
        cap = cv2.VideoCapture(video)
        number_of_frames = int(cap.get(cv2.CAP_PROP_FRAME_COUNT))
        video_generator(name_of_video, video, cap, number_of_frames)

        del B
        del background
        gc.collect()
```

Answer (score 0):

- http://www.digi.com/wiki/developer/index.php/Python_Garbage_Collection
- http://docs.python.org/library/gc.html
- http://arctrix.com/nas/python/gc/

There's no definitive resource on how Python does its garbage collection (other than the source code itself), but those 3 links should give you a pretty good idea.

Update

The source is actually pretty helpful. How much you get out of it depends on how well you read C, but the comments are actually very helpful. Skip down to the collect() function and the comments explain the process well (albeit in very technical terms).

Comment: Thank you, also do you know why deleting B and background messes up the code when I try to run it? I get the error message "NameError: name 'background' is not defined" even though it should be created in every iteration.

Comment: @ParkerMays: Those names aren't in the scope you're trying to delete them from. You created them in `video_generator` (so they disappear when it returns anyway), and they never existed in global scope (which is where you're trying to `del` them).

Answer (score 0):

As an answer to your top-level question: Explicitly `del`ing the last reference to an object, and calling `gc.collect()` are the closest thing to manually clearing RAM Python has, and neither one of them is typically needed. Function locals are cleaned automatically when the function exits (as if each local name was `del`ed), and cyclic GC runs every few hundred allocations by default, which is usually fine, unless you have huge objects participating in cycles. Aside from that, the general rule is to explicitly call clean up methods (or better, use `with` statements when available) to ensure resources are released promptly, and don't keep references around longer than you need them (if you keep a global `list` that you keep `append`ing to, no GC can save you, as you *asked* to hold onto that stuff forever).

For specific recommendations:

I believe you should be calling `cap.release()` on your `VideoCapture` object when you're done with it; leaving one open for every loop over `range(number_of_videos)`  is probably tying up resources for quite a while. In theory the docs claim the destructor calls `release` for you, but it's best to call it explicitly to be sure, especially since reference cycles are surprisingly easy to trigger, and that can end up delaying (or for poorly written or Python 2 extension modules, block completely) the clean up you're expecting.

Your repeated calls to `np.append` are going to slow you down a lot as well; `np.append` creates a copy of the input and appends to it, which is going to act as a form of [Schlemiel the Painter's algorithm](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Schlemiel_the_Painter's_algorithm); each new frame ends up copying all the data from before, plus the new data, and that prior data keeps growing and growing. I'd suggest keeping `A`/`a` as plain Python `list`s that you call `.append` on, and only recombine once at the end, to avoid quadratic growth in memory copying.

I'll also note that your `del B` and `del background` make no sense; they exist solely within the scope of `video_generator`, and you're trying to `del` them while at global scope (after they've been cleaned up anyway, and from a scope where they *never* existed). Explicit `del`s of names is usually not needed; locals are cleaned up when a function exits (assuming no other references exist), so you're trying to do the runtime's job for it when you don't need to.

Comment: I made the changes you suggested and it definitely made an improvement, but it is still slowing down exponentially. Do you have any ideas of what else it could be?